# Pass a parameter from a text box

Tags: java, android, http, url

Based on this article (http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/http/android-how-to-send-http-get-request-to-servlet-using-apache-http-client/), made ​​a simple http client. But I can not add parameters to url.

I’m trying to pass a parameter from a text box:

```
EditText editTextValue
public String givenValue = editTextValue.getText (). toString ();
public final String URL = "http://example.com/script.php?ip =" + givenValue;
```

But getting this error:

```
ERROR / AndroidRuntime (7103): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
at com.example.MainActivity. (MainActivity.java: 39) (public String givenValue = editTextValue.getText (). toString () ;)
```

How can I fix it?

Sorry for my English.

**Update:**

Full Source:

```
package com.example.App;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import android.widget.EditText;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button btnGetInfo;
    TextView textView;
    EditText editTextValue;

    public String givenValue = editTextValue.getText().toString();

    public String URL = "http://example.com/script.php?value=" + givenValue;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

      findViewsById();

        btnGetInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void findViewsById() {
        btnGetInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGetInfo);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editTextValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextValue);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

            GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
            task.execute(new String[] {URL});
    }

    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String output = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                output = getOutputFromUrl(url);
            }
            return output;
        }

        private String getOutputFromUrl(String url) {
            String output = null;
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                output = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
            textView.setText(output);
        }
    }
}
```

And log:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.App/com.example.App.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.App.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:28)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Your English is fine but your logcat could use some work ;) Could you post the full logcat please. Also, have you initialized your `EditText`?

Comment: I'm just starting to learn programming, and in order not to mislead people post the entire source code and log

Comment: No problem but always post full logcat when you have a crash. See my answer, it should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your EditText is probably null.
Did you setup edittext before calling the getText()?
Try:

```
EditText editTextValue = (EditText) findViewByItd(R.id.yourEditText);
```

Base on the tutorial, you can put this line in findViewsById.

```
private void findViewsById() {
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTxt);
    editTextValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextValue);
}
```

**Edit :**
You have to move

```
public String givenValue = editTextValue.getText().toString();
```

to somewhere proper.

editTextValue.getText() shouldn't be called before onCreate and findViewById.

Maybe you could try placing the line in onPostExecute or onClick. (Just for test)

**Update 2:**

Move givenValue and URL to onClick

**NOTE: I HAVEN'T TESTED THE FOLLOWING CODE:**

```
package com.example.App;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import android.widget.EditText;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button btnGetInfo;
    TextView textView;
    EditText editTextValue;

    public String givenValue;

    public String URL;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

      findViewsById();

        btnGetInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void findViewsById() {
        btnGetInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGetInfo);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editTextValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextValue);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
            givenValue = editTextValue.getText().toString();
            URL = "http://example.com/script.php?value=" + givenValue;
            GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
            task.execute(new String[] {URL});
    }

    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String output = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                output = getOutputFromUrl(url);
            }
            return output;
        }

        private String getOutputFromUrl(String url) {
            String output = null;
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                output = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
            textView.setText(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but to me it did not help.

Comment: Please see my edit. Anyway, it's hard to explain everything if you don't have Android background. I recommend you to at least skim some basic tutorial before doing coding.

Comment: Yes, everything works the way I wanted to. Thank you very much for your help :)
I read the book learning, but learning the examples given me better (after reading the book I did not know how to solve your problem.)

Comment: It's alright. I know some people prefer learning by doing. Glad I can help.

Answer (score 0):

set findViewById for editTextValue first then getText()

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems here. The first being that you are trying to call `getText()` on an `EditText` that has not yet been initialized. But even if you had, you would still get the same error because you haven't inflated your `layout` yet. You need to call `setContentViw()` before trying to access `View`s in the `layout`. Also, you can't try to access the `View`s before `onCreate()` has run. It should look something more like the following...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button btnGetInfo;
TextView textView;
EditText editTextValue;

public String givenValue = ""; 

public String URL = "http://example.com/script.php?value=";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    findViewsById();  // its fine to use this method but do it before trying to get the value from the EditText
    givenValue  = editTextValue.getText().toString();
    URL = URL.concat(givenValue);  // there are different ways but use one to concatenate the Strings
```

This method `findViewsById()` should work but its awfully close to a native Android function so I would consider renaming it to something like `init()` or `loadViews()` or something else.

Comment: The parameter is not passed in the url, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to see *where* the problem is? This would fix your initial problem.

Comment: You are still trying to get the value from an `EditText` before initializing it. Look at my answer again.

Comment: Yes, this is my fault (negligence + lack of knowledge). But I corrected :)
Thank you for your help. Both you and Entryleveldev saying the right things, I just could not use them.